# array_unique only returns one record

Tags: php, array-unique

In the code below:

```
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT DISTINCT title,courseId,location from training');  
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
$uu = array_unique($results);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($uu);
echo "</pre>";
```

I only get 1 results from `print_r($uu);`

If I remove `array_unique` All (30+) rows are returned. (No, not all of them are duplicates) :)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT `var_dump()` results:

```
array(23) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(26) "String Here"
    ["courseId"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["location"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(26) "Another String Here"
    ["courseId"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["location"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(24) "Third String Here"
    ["courseId"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["location"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
```

etc...

Comment: I cant show the exact contents because of privacy issues, but I'll post the structure in just a minute...

Comment: @Paul show a small sanitized sample then

Comment: Why are you using `array_unique` in the 1st place?  Isn't that what `DISTINCT` does?

Comment: I would manually iterate through the array and check for duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585208/how-can-you-make-a-multidimensional-array-unique

Comment: @Rocket for some reason `DISTINCT` isn't returning a unique set...

Comment: @Paul: DISTINCT means that each row in the result rer will be different from the others (the rows can share *some* values, just not *all* values).  DISTINCT acts on the entire row, not just one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual:

> Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

Further:

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same.

When an array is cast to a string you get "Array".

---

Why are you calling `array_unique` anyway?  Your database already ensured uniqueness.

I'm not exactly sure on the details but this seems to be what you want.  Still learning SQL myself.

```
SELECT title, courseId, location
FROM training
GROUP BY title;
```

Comment: "Your database already ensured uniqueness." that was another issue I was having, it's not retrieving a unique data set. There are some duplicates. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: just `title` would be sufficient

Comment: Your SQL query is equivalent to just selecting every row.

Comment: Thanks @LeviMorrison I tried that SQL before you removed it and as Rocket said, it selects everything.

Comment: @LeviMorrison It looks like that might have done the trick. Gona take it for a test drive... ;)

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding of `array_unique` it does not recursively iterate through an array. It will see that every value of `$uu === array()` therefore removing all but one of the values whilst preserving the key. I wouldn't be surprised if the key is always 0 as a result.

In the manual see the notes:

> Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Paul: You'd have to implement your own solution :P

Comment: @Paul just a thought but I'd look towards the SQL query to deliver unique rows based on a specific (or multiple) fields. Iterating through the array in PHP and then running unique checks on each sub array would be far more resource intensive.

Comment: That's what `DISTINCT` was supposed to accomplish, but it doesn't work. Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546804/select-distinct-from-multiple-fields-using-sql it should help you answer your question succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

The `DISTINCT` keyword acts on the entire row, not just one field.   Adding `DISTINCT` means that each row in the result set will be unique (compared to each other row).  It's possible for rows to share *some* fields, just not *all* fields.

Answer (score 0):

array_unique() compares items by their string representation. As the manual notes,

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if  (string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2

String conversion of an array will always yield "Array" so PHP thinks all items are the same and array_unique() only returns one items.

To work around this, you will have to write your own function, probably making sure of in_array(). Since the rows are from the database, you should be able to rework your SQL so only unique rows are returned.