# how to merge two arrays without duplication using a certain value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

in PHP, I have these two arrays, first one is "$ar1", the second is "$ar2":

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1505
            [category] => blue
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1805
            [category] => red
        )

)
Array
(
    [1777] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1505
            [category] => yellow
        )

    [1877] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1507
            [category] => blue
        )

)
```

I want to add $ar1 to $ar2 but only if the "id" is not already in $ar2.
for example: the one with id "1505" should not be added to $ar2.
here is the code I used:

$ar3 = array_merge_recursive($ar1, $ar2);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you make a multidimensional array unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585208/how-can-you-make-a-multidimensional-array-unique)

Comment: also: I don't want to use foreach for this to compare the "id" part because this is just a sample and the arrays size are actually huge so i'm concerned about performance

Comment: I would have use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4585286/6487675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility might by to first extract the ids from `$ar2` using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$ar2 = array( '1777' => (object) array('id' => '1505', 'category' => 'yellow'), '1877' => (object) array('id' => '1507', 'category' => 'blue'), );
$ids = array_column($ar1, 'id');
$ar3 = array_merge_recursive($ar1, array_filter($ar2, function($x) use ($ids) {
    return !in_array($x->id, $ids);
}));

print_r($ar3);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1505
            [category] => blue
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1805
            [category] => red
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1507
            [category] => blue
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/SB4un)

Comment: You have id 1805 twice - why?

Comment: @DavidWinder I have updated it, I switched the filtering.

Comment: array_merge will do here won't it?

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most php-ish code (I guess there is some array function which can do this better), but it's working:

```
$array1 = array(
    new Dummy(1505,"blue"),
    new Dummy(1805,"red")
);

$array2 = array(
    new Dummy(1505,"yellow"),
    new Dummy(1507,"blue")
);

$array3 = [];

foreach($array1 as $value)
{
    $array3[$value->id] = $value;
}

foreach($array2 as $value)
{
    if(!isset($array3[$value->id]))
    {
        $array3[$value->id] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($array3);
```

I just made a Dummy class, since I wanted to be as near to your data as I could. This uses the key of the map (arrays are maps in PHP) as primary key. First, you iterate over your always setting array, then over the one which only gets applied to the final array if the id wasn't set yet -> done. This prints:

```
array(3) { 
[1505]=> object(Dummy)#1 (2) { ["id"]=> int(1505) ["category"]=> string(4) "blue"}
[1805]=> object(Dummy)#2 (2) { ["id"]=> int(1805) ["category"]=> string(3) "red" } 
[1507]=> object(Dummy)#4 (2) { ["id"]=> int(1507) ["category"]=> string(4) "blue" } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to merge array

```
array_merge($array1,$array2)
```

Comment: You can merge, but this would not filter out ids that are already in the first array.  https://3v4l.org/U46vj

Answer (score 0):

try this, function is from this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$array1 = array(
                    array('id'=>'1505', 'category'=>'blue'),
                    array('id'=>'1805', 'category'=>'red')
                );

      $array2 = array(
                    array('id'=>'1505', 'category'=>'yellow'),
                    array('id'=>'1507', 'category'=>'blue')
                );
      $array3 = array_merge($array1, $array2);

      function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
          $temp_array = array(); 
          $i = 0; 
          $key_array = array(); 

          foreach($array as $val) { 
              if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
                  $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
                  $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
              } 
              $i++; 
          } 
          return $temp_array; 
      } 
      $details = unique_multidim_array($array3,'id');
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($details);
      die;
```